# Angular2 Reactive Forms Validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple component that implements reactive forms and sets up 7 input fields which are `select` inputs.

I am trying to apply a validator on it to force at least one of them to contain a value.

**Component:**

```
renderForm() {
        this.importForm = this.fb.group({
            costCenter: [],
            area: [],
            silo: [],
            department: [],
            location: [],
            segment: [],
            role: []
        },
            {
                validator: (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
                    return this.validateFilter(formGroup);
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see that at least one of the filter
     * options have been filled out prior to searching
     * for employees.
     *
     * @param formGroup
     */
    validateFilter(formgroup: FormGroup) {
        if (formgroup.controls["costCenter"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["area"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["silo"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["department"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["location"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["segment"].value ||
            formgroup.controls["role"].value
        ) {
            return { validateFilter: true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I submit my form an inspect the `form` itself, it keeps saying that its valid, even though none of the inputs have been filled out.

When I look at the individual form control values, they are displaying as `null`, verifying that not value has been stored.

Anything noticeable that I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

Not sure if this matters but a value of my input is an array:

[image]

I would think that this is still considered to be `true` when testing to see if it has a value?

**Update 2:**
Here is a snippet of my HTML. This snippet is the same for each dropdown, just references a different function to populate it.

```
<tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Area</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="area" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getAreas()" placeholder="Select one or more Areas">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Update 3:

As requested, here is the full HTML template.

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Cost Center</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <ng-select formControlName="costCenter" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getCostCenters()" placeholder="Select one or more Cost Centers">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Area</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="area" name="area" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getAreas()" placeholder="Select one or more Areas">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Silo</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="silo" name="silo" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getSilos()" placeholder="Select one or more Silos">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Department</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="department" name="department" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getDepartments()" placeholder="Select one or more Departments">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Location</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="location" name="location" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getLocations()" placeholder="Select one or more Locations">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Segment</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="segment" name="segment" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getSegments()" placeholder="Select one or more Segments">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-2 strong">Role</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ng-select formControlName="role" name="role" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="getRoles()" placeholder="Select one or more Roles">
                        </ng-select>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**Update 4:**

As a test, I commented out all of the validation logic and just returned `return { validFilter: true };` expecting it to tell my form that its `valid`. However, this was not the case and the form is still `invalid`.

Seems like there may be an underlying issue somewhere else?

Comment: This will be invalid because department, location and etc is null. Can you show your template?

Comment: @brijmcq I added an HTML snippet to the question.

Comment: @brijmcq - I added the `name=` property to each element, resulting in the same issue.

Comment: It seems that you get the data on "area" formcontrol. Can you show the other formcontrols? I.e the department or location etc

Comment: @brijmcq Updated with the full template as requested.

Comment: just one more thing, can you show your formgroup?

Comment: Here is the formGroup that wraps the table posted above: `<form [formGroup]="importForm" #f="ngForm" *ngIf="fields">`

Comment: your code looks ok, Can you try to remove #f="ngForm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could be wrong, but at first glance it looks like you have the validator mixed up. It should be the following:

```
/**
 * Checks to see that at least one of the filter
 * options have been filled out prior to searching
 * for employees.
 *
 * @param formGroup
 */
validateFilter(formgroup: FormGroup) {
    if (formgroup.controls["costCenter"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["area"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["silo"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["department"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["location"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["segment"].value ||
        formgroup.controls["role"].value
    ) {
        return null
    } else {
        return { noFilterOptionsSet: true };
    }
}
```

The way validators work is that a "valid" validator returns null, in other words: "I didn't find anything wrong". If it finds something it returns an object with a descriptively named property with a boolean value that further describes the state of the property, most likely "true". This is used to trigger different errors and inform the form of which error occured so you can apply different labels and error messages.

Comment: I think this is it! A quick test showed that it passed validation when I selected one value for a single input. However, when I removed the value, looks like my form kept the value as an empty array instead of null. `role:Array(0)` vs when it started as `role: null`. I just need to find see if I can reset this to null upon removal and then the validation should reset back to invalid upon removal. Will accept this answer here shortly.

Comment: You may need to have a "clear" button that uses the `setValue` method on the controls to return them to a `null` state.

Comment: I got it working. I just set my form controls to an empty array `costCenter: [[]]` and then in my validator, I do `formgroup.controls["costCenter"].value.length`.

Nice work on catching that :)

Comment: help needed on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular @joshrathke

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
this.importForm = this.fb.group({
            costCenter: ['', [Validators.required],
            area:  ['', [Validators.required],
            silo: ['', [Validators.required],
            department: ['', [Validators.required],
            location: ['', [Validators.required],
            segment: ['', [Validators.required],
            role:  ['', [Validators.required]
        });
```

This would make your form with a default values of ' ' with required validation. The reason why the validators are in array is because you can also add multiple validator like this

```
 department: ['', [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(3)]],
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I gave this a try and now even when I select a value for anyone of the inputs, the form is `invalid`. As a test, I even tried to select a value for all of the inputs and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: help needed on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular @brijmcq

Answer (score 0):

My code looks a bit different ... not sure if it would change things for you:

```
validateFilter(formgroup: FormGroup) {
    if (formgroup.get("costCenter").value ||
        formgroup.get("area").value ||
        formgroup.get("silo").value ||
        formgroup.get("department").value ||
        formgroup.get("location").value ||
        formgroup.get("segment").value ||
        formgroup.get("role").value
    ) {
        return { 'validateFilter': true };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

- In the return statement, the return value is a string and a boolean, so I enclosed it in quotes.
- I also used .get instead of .controls, but that should not matter.

I have a working example of a custom group validator here for reference if that helps: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final-Updated

Comment: I gave this a try and ran into the same issue. The whole form is invalid, even when I select an input. I updated my original question to make sure there isn't an issue with my value being an array. Would this still test as `true?` I am using a plugin `ng-select` which allows me to select multiple values from the dropdown, thus the final output being an array.

Comment: so it sounds like each input element then *has* a value that is the array. Have you tried checking the array length then instead of checking for null? `formgroup.get("costCenter").value.length`

Comment: Good call, I tried adding the `.length` check on there, however, it results in the same invalid form.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: help needed on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular @DeborahK