# Form validation is not working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I want to check whether the dropdown is empty.

Need to show the required message and

If not empty, enable the submit button.

If empty, disable the submit button. Below is my html

Below is my html

```
<form  [formGroup]="myForm"  (ngSubmit)="save()" >
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Element List"  (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.name">
      {{ element.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'name')">Please choose an name</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select  formControlName="symbol"  placeholder="Symbol List" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of selectedElementSymbol" [value]="element.symbol">
      {{ element.symbol }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="myForm.hasError('required', 'symbol')">Please choose an symbol</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<div mat-dialog-actions>

  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>
</div>
</form>
```

below is my component

```
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  symbol = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [this.name],
      symbol: [this.symbol],
    });
  }

  save() {

    console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }

}
```

[updated demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-9bxei5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently assigning formcontrols to your formcontrol, whereas you want to assign value to your form controls. Below you are assigning form control `name` to formcontrol `name`:

**WRONG:**

```
name = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': [this.name, Validators.required],
  // ...
});
```

so instead, just declare name, do what you want with the value, then assign that value to your form control...

**CORRECT:**

```
name: string;

this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': [this.name, Validators.required],
  // ...
});
```

Then just add `[disabled]="!myForm.valid"` on your submit button.

As for the other question, by default Angular material doesn't show error message unless the field has been touched, so you need to have a custom error state matcher that shows the error even when field is not touched (if that is what you want):

```
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control.invalid);
  }
}
```

and in your TS, declare a error state matcher:

```
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

and use in template:

```
<mat-select formControlName="name" ... [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
```

Here's your

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-jxtaj4?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

Comment: need one help @AJT_82 only when user touch that time we need to show required message

Comment: @itsme well, just add a `control.touched` to the error state matcher :)

Comment: hai need one help when i do edit data is not getting populated (i made some changes) . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-nkmffh?file=app/table-basic-example.ts .help m eout

Comment: help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927779/autocomplete-is-not-working-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the validator into the form builder object.

Have a quick look at:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#validatorsrequired

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required] ],
});
```

As for the button:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>
```

Comment: here is the link can you help  me on this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-9bxei5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Answer (score 0):

To make the submit button disabled ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062051/angular2-forms-submit-button-disabled))

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" mat-button cdkFocusInitial>Add</button>
```

In order to check whether the dropdown is empty or not, you need to make the form fields required like

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'name': [this.name, Validators.required],
  'symbol': [this.symbol, [Validators.required]]
});
```

Inorder to show the error highlight you need to add an ngClass in the templete like.

```
[ngClass]="{'error': myForm.controls.name.valid == false}"
```

Comment: i added above code but its not working can you pls help me out ..here is the link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-9bxei5?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: did u check the demo @Nitheesh

Comment: i am not getting any error but above code not working

Comment: help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927779/autocomplete-is-not-working-in-angular